# Creating an Arraylist of the specified parameter's type or its subtype

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I intend to create a function with the following signature -

```
public static List<? extends Model> getList(Model T, int numberOfItems, StringReader reader)
```

Now, inside this function, I want to create an ArrayList that will contain the same type of objects as T **or any of its subclasses**, i.e T could be a Model object or any of its subtypes.

So far, I tried -

```
   List < ? extends T> list = new ArrayList();
```

But it didn't work. How to get this to work?

Comment: In `getList(Model T, ...)` you are using `T` as a **parameter name**, not a type name.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yes, that's right. I want the List to be of the type of that parameter.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I edited the question's title.

Comment: the type of that parameter is `Model`...

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt , but I could pass a subclass of Model to this function.

Comment: @CodeBlue: but not in a way that will be relevant to the type system.

Comment: You can't solve your problem by Generics. What you are describing is the **runtime** type of the argument, whereas generics only exist at compile time.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you're right. What I want to do is this - specify the type of object somehow (i.e. the class of the object) and the function will create an object of that class (this object will then be put into an ArrayList). I thought this could be achieved with generics. If not, how could I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to pass in the `Class` instance as a type marker. Something like this:

```
public static <T extends Model> List<T> getList(
    Class<T> c, int numberOfItems, StringReader reader)
{
  final List<T> l = new ArrayList<T>();
  try { for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) l.add(c.newInstance());
  } catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
  return l;
}
```

I don't know how you want to use the `StringReader` so I left it aside. Call the method with a class literal. Say you've got a `SubModel extends Model`, then

```
final List<SubModel> l = getList(SubModel.class, 10, reader);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want is this:

```
public static <T extends Model> List<T> getList(T model, int numberOfItems, StringReader reader)
```

This specifies that the method has a type parameter `T` which extends `Model`, so the method can be used with any such type and for that call will return a `List` of the type that was passed as first parameter. Inside the method:

```
List <T> list = new ArrayList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you're asking for is

```
public static <M extends Model> List<M> getList(M t, int numberOfItems, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static <T extends Model> List<T> getList(final Model t, final int numberOfItems, final StringReader reader)
{
    final List<T> aaa=new ArrayList<T>();
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This returns a list of type T (and T is either of type Model or one of its subclasses).

```
public static <T extends Model> List<T> getList(T object, int numberOfItems, StringReader reader) {
    return Arrays.asList(object);
}
```